# Hashing Function Not Responding

Tags: python, hash, crc32

I am trying out the Hashing and i want to match the output of `323322056` to the `base64` string, such that their `crc32` values are equal.

**test1.py**

```
import binascii
result = binascii.crc32('supersecretpassword')
print(result) #323322056
```

**test2.py**

```
import binascii, socket, base64

socket.setdefaulttimeout(0)

i = 0
while True:
    if binascii.crc32(base64.encodestring(i)) == 323322056:
        print(base64.encodestring(i))
        i += 1
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

**Full StackTrace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ajay/PycharmProjects/itertools/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    if binascii.crc32(base64.encodestring(i)) == 323322056:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\base64.py", line 313, in encodestring
    for i in range(0, len(s), MAXBINSIZE):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

**Expected Output:**

```
MTIxMjY5MTAwNg==
```

Such that this condition is satisfied:

```
import binascii

print(binascii.crc32("MTIxMjY5MTAwNg=="))
# 323322056
```

Comment: What is the full traceback of your exception? And what does the `socket.setdefaulttimeout(0)` have to do with your question?

Comment: Are you planning to brute force a CRC32 value? Then note that a bytestring of all nulls of different lengths will produce different `base64` values. Bruteforcing a password this way will take a *long* time indeed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, i am just trying out options :D

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to encode an integer value:

```
base64.encodestring(i)
```

The `base64.encodestring()` function requires a bytestring as input. Did you mean to use:

```
base64.encodestring(bytes((i,)))
```

perhaps? This will only work up to `i = 255` however. To produce bytestrings of increasing length, including nulls, you could use a generator function:

```
from itertools import product, count

def generate_bytes():
    for l in count(1):
        for sequence in product(range(256), repeat=l):
            yield bytes(sequence)
```

then loop over that:

```
for attempt in generate_bytes():
    encoded = base64.encodestring(attempt)
    if binascii.crc32(encoded) == 323322056:
        print(encoded)
```

Be prepared to wait a long time, however, as it requires 2574816081756422681317790513970423263275217508 iterations to produce the bytestring `b'supersecretpassword'`. Presumably there are collisions before that point but I wouldn't hold my breath too long waiting for one.

If all you wanted to use was digits, then just `str(i).encode('ascii')` is enough:

```
from itertools import count

for attempt in count():
    encoded = base64.encodestring(str(attempt).encode('ascii'))
    if binascii.crc32(encoded) == 323322056:
        print(encoded)
```

Comment: @ajkumar25: Because `bytes(integer)` will produce a `bytes` object of length integer with nulls.